# Fortran infinity check shows infinity though the values is not

Tags: fortran, infinity

I'm sharing a part of my code, where I'm trying to check if the value of a varible (PF) becomes infinity of not. It turns out the test find it to be infinite although, in reality, it is much smaller than the highest floating number that can be stored in [Fortan](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs151/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch06s09.html).

```
    PF=0.d0
    PF_before=PF
    do i=0,Nstates-1
          PF=PF+exp(-beta*E(i))
    end do

    flag_reduce=0

    print*,'PF-1,PF=',PF-1,PF


    !if (PF-1==PF) then ! True if PF is infinity
    if (IEEE_IS_FINITE(PF)) then ! True if PF is infinity
            print*,'PF is infinite!'
        if (flag_reduce==1) then
                 PF=PF_before ! Set PF to its prev finite value
        end if 
      end if

    print*,'Partition function =',PF
```

The output that I'm getting:

```
 PF-1,PF=   87146548995742.281        87146548995743.281
 PF is infinite!
 Partition function =   87146548995743.281
```

What's going wrong here? [I have compiled with gfortran.]

Comment: `if (IEEE_IS_FINITE(PF)) then ! True if PF is infinity`: it's true if PF is _finite_.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood the IEEE function. But when `PF=PF-1=1.0367621231669302E+023`, I get infinity. Why is it so? Isn't the largest positive float value  `1.7976 x 10^308`?

Comment: What is the value of `huge(pf)`?